# Client side validation using ajax call does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I open a modal dialog when a row in a jQuery data table is clicked and populate it with data taken from the selected row. User can update some fields and submit. I have client side validation; basic types like this text is required or select something from a drop down list.

For one field I need to check for duplicate values (e.g. duplicate name) which requires server side check. The problem is when I do a server side check, the postback closes the modal dialog. So, for this part I used ajax, as suggested.

Following @Rafalon suggestion, I managed to make an ajax call to validate the input. However, when the function valiadteSubmit() is called, it goes through other validations, then executes the ajax call and exits, closing the modal, even though in .done() I can see the error is caught. Please see below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg fade in ui-draggable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tbName">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="tbName" class="form-control" clientidmode="Static" />
                            <span id="lblErrName" class="field-validation-error pull-left" style="display: inline"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div id="divNewButtons" style="text-align: center;">
                    <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-info2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Cancel">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function (event) {
    var isValid = validateSubmit();

    if (isValid) {
        // do whatever
    }
    else
        return false;
});

function validateSubmit() {debugger
    var isValid = true;
    var name = $("#tbName").val();
    var districtID = $("#ddlDistrict").val();

    var nameErr = false;

    // this gets executed after other validations following it
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/services/mpoo.asmx/NameExists',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "Name": name, "DistrictID": districtID }),
    }).done(function (data) {debugger
        nameErr = JSON.parse(data.d);  // this is "true" or "false"
        if (nameErr == 'true') {
            // This error never gets displayed because modal closes
            $("#lblErrName").text("Duplicate Name within selected District");
            $("#lblErrName").show();
            isValid = false;  // I tried "return false;"
        }
    });
    if (name == '') {
        $("#lblErrName").text("Name is required");
        $("#lblErrName").show();
        isValid = false; // also tried "return false;"
    }
    ... // other validations here
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: You could use javascript `getJson` to call a server action that will check for duplicates without submitting the form

Comment: You're using Web Forms?

Comment: yes, it is an asp.net web form.

Comment: @Rafalon can you show me a snippet?

Comment: Updated question based on getJson() suggestion. I am just not clear about significance of "data" and whether my approach is correct or not.

Comment: The ajax call will never cause your function to return false when invalid because it is asynchronous. The function will be completed before the asynchronous request even returns from the server.

Comment: @NoBullMan sorry for belated reply. My suggestion was more about if you had an mvc app, I don't know if it suits well a webforms app. It was having a get action like `public ActionResult ValidateField(string value){ return Json(isDuplicateValue(value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}` and in javascript `$('#field').change(function(){ getJson(getAbsolutePath() + ValidateField, { value: getValue('field') }, function(data){ /*display validation message depending on bool value of data*/ })})`

Answer (score 0):

For this you can surround your controls that needs validation inside modal with a `updatepanel`. You can use for a easy way `onTextChanged` to trigger a validation

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

           </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

on codebehind

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomValidator1.Validate();
}

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
///do the validation here return true if passes else false.
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

The  updatepanel will prevent from page reload so the modal will not close. This is a small example of how you could do it.

Comment: wrapping modal dialog in update panel did not help. I have updated my question, which partially works. It checks for duplicate name and returns true/false correctly. However, when false, it does not display the error.

Comment: @NoBullMan dont wrap the modal itself inside the updatepanel. This has to be inside the contents of the modal. everything in the modal gets rebuild so the modal will get closed if you wrap this arround the modal.

Comment: this still doesn't work. Modal dialog is a bootstrap modal, all validations are done client side except for this one (check duplicate name) which requires server side access. I used ajax call to check for duplicate name. The problem is ajax (the .done() part) is bypassed first, goes through all other validations, comes back to .done() part and correctly determines name is duplicate and then closes the modal!

Comment: @NoBullMan i edited the post. Did full copy of a modal to give full example. Tested and it does not close the modal as expected also shows the error if returned a false.